# While adding google font to my blog in blogger I got error in Header Section

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, blogs

Please help me solve the error displayed in the image below.

It says:

```
Error parsing XML, line 5, column 71: The reference to entity "display" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

```
<strike>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
</strike>
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersand `&` to `&amp;` in XML code.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

just change `&`  with `&amp;`  
The problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

The html code will be like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

For your kind attention, you can avoid display=swap. And I'll recommend this one:

```
<link as='style' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' media='all' onload='this.onload=null;this.rel=&apos;stylesheet&apos;' rel='preload'/>
```